# Ubuntu is installing to USB and not SSD

Tags: system-installation

So I've been trying to get my Ubuntu 16.04 to work for a very long time now, and now I see the problem. Ubuntu is installing to my usb drive rather than installing to my SSD which is what I want to happen. Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo parted -l` (run from the live Ubuntu system that comes with the Ubuntu installation medium)? Thanks.

Comment: Be careful what partition you are on!  Can you post a list of them or write them down and cancel the install?  hint "SD#"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you make sure when you installing you take a very close look at when you partition your drive for installation - Uninstall and try again. 
 Good Luck